# Is it possible to have myget work with git source code that has ignored files?

Tags: git, myget

In my git source code, I ignored the external configuration file, named appsettings.config. And in Visual Studio projects I have projects referencing this file as a link. But when I tried to set up the integration between MyGet and git, I found that MyGet requires the appsettings.config to be present in order to make a successful build.
So is there a way to solve this dilemma?

Thanks,
Nico

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a convention-based build, or a custom build script?

In theory, if you're not doing anything fancy, both should just work.
First thing to try is to see if a local build actually works properly based on only the git sources. That means, exclude/remove anything locally in your repository that is not present in the git repository.

To do so, you can run `git clean -xdf` and attempt another local build. Does that work? If not, you'll likely be able to spot and fix the build issue.

If it does, I'll need more details :)

**UPDATE based on below comments:**

So, the question is actually a git question on how to ignore local changes to a file tracked by the git repository.

There is a way to tell git to (locally!) ignore changes to an already committed file, so it no longer appears in your pending changes or commits:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/appsettings.config
```

Source: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index/

To undo the above, simply use `--no-assume-unchanged` instead.

Comment: If i set git to ignore the appsettings.config file, the code on git will not build, because this file is link referenced by lots of projects. However, if i don't ignore it, this file is likely to be messy as all it contains is environment-specific configurations, such as absolute file/folder path, local web api url. This is why i extracted it out and used '<appSettings file="appsettings.config"></appSettings>' in the web.config of referencing projects.

Comment: AFAIK, those settings are runtime settings and do not affect building the code. In other words, you can leave the file in the repo with dummy/fake/empty values.

Comment: The problem is not the file's content, but whether or not it's being managed by git. If l put it in git and leave its content blank or dummy, and i have to use real config settings on my local dev environment, git will regard it as modified file and show in commit list all the time.

Comment: If i ignore it, it won't be present in git repo. Then the build process from myget will fail because it can't find such files. That's why i said it's a dilemma. I need to ignore it and i can't ignore it.

Comment: first add to repo, then ignore locally :)

Comment: What do you mean ignore locally? Isn't any local change supposed to appear in commit list?

Comment: Yes, unless you tell git to --assume-unchanged for the particular file, in which case it will ignore any changes you do to the file after it has been committed.

Comment: Thanks. I did some research on this command. It looks like it's more recommended to use the skip-worktree option. Anyway, both methods have the drawback the this command needs to be executed on every machine individually as that can't be pushed to the remote repo. i guess this is it. there's no elegant solution.